# I don't understand a Michael Aschbacher's proof

Tags: group-theory

I can't understand so much the last paragraph (page 165) of the proof of the lemma 32.3 (pages 163-165) in M. Aschbacher, *Finite Group Theory* about Thompson Factorization. Here I post the statement of the lemma and the proof given in the book.

- [Lemma and proof - first part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvb4o.png)
- [Proof - second part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4boW.png)

In particular:

1. Why $E\leq DC_G([D,V])$?
2. Why from the action of $D$ on $[D,V]$ it follows that $m(E/C_E([D,V])\leq m([D,V]/C_{[D,V]}(E))$?

Here some definitions.

- $m(G)$ is the $p$-rank of the group $G$, i.e. the maximum number of generators of an elementary abelian $p$-subgroup of $G$.
- If $V$ is a $GF(p)G$-module $\mathcal{P}(G,V)$ consists of the nontrivial elementary abelian $p$-subgroups $A$ of $G$ such that $m(A)+m(C_V(A))\geq m(B)+m(C_V(B))$ for each $B\leq G$.
- A subset $\mathcal{P}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(G,V)$ is stable if $G$ permutes $\mathcal{P}$ via conjugation and, whenever $A\in\mathcal{P}$ and $B$ is a nontrivial subgroup of $A$ with $m(A)+m(C_V(A))=m(B)+m(C_V(B))$ then $B\in\mathcal{P}$.

I know that this proof is very technical but I need to get it :(
Is there anyone familiar with this subject that can help me? :)
Thanks!

Comment: You could at least post the statement of the lemma. I bet if you took the time to make sure you could carefully explain what everything is -- $E,\ DC_G([D, V])$, the action, the stuff with the $m$'s, etc, and the context in which it's all appearing -- not only would you be closer to understanding the proof, but your question might have sufficient context to be reopened.

Comment: I'm sorry...Done :)